# Is PDO-DEBUG secure?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, prepared-statement

I am no security expert. My knowledge extends as far as "always use prepared staemtens and bind any SQL query parameters which are taken from user input".

Like,  I imagine, many others, I would very much like to debug my PDO queries right there in my PHP code.

[PDO-DEBUG](https://github.com/panique/pdo-debug) looks like a great solution, even if I would have to rewrite my queries.

My uncertainty is where it says

> Your PDO block probably looks like this:
>
> ```
> $sql = "INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (:col1, :col2, :col3)";
> ```
>
> and this, right ?
>
> ```
> $query->execute(array(':col1' => $param_1, ':col2' => $param_2, ':col3' => $param_3));
> ```

because mine doesn't. It looks like

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (:col1, :col2, :col3"));
$stmt->bind_param(":col1", $col1);     
$stmt->bind_param(":col2", $col2);     
$stmt->bind_param(":col3", $col3);
$stmt->execute();
```

(the syntax may be slightly wrong; I am doing it from memory, with no access to my code or a PHP interpreter).

My point is that `preapre()` and `bind()` perform some "magicks", and I would not trade the security which they provide for some nice debugging.

Should I be concerned? Or should I go ahead and us it?

Comment: `bind_param` isn't PDO, it's mysqli_. PDO is `bindParam()`.

Comment: Thaks (+1) Like I said, I did that from memory.  Can you please update the questoin for me? The point of the quesiton is the security of that approach, so I would not like to distract people from it with my poor coding skills.

Comment: this stuff is irrelevant to PDO-DEBUG, it's native feature of PDO

Comment: Are you telling me that I lose no security if I use PDO-DEBUg as directed, as opposed to prepare() then bind() ? If so, please feel free to post an answer

Comment: There's no difference in security whether you pass your arguments to `execute` or use `bind*()`, they're equally secure. The PDO-debug library merely needs the arguments in one array and doesn't accept them individually. FWIW, you can simply call it with `PdoDebugger::show($sql, ['col1' => $col1, ...])` without changing anything about your query.

Comment: No need to post the answer is linked already